# Setup a cronjob for PHP script in ubuntu & PHP

Tags: php, cron

I want to setup a cronjob for PHP script in ubuntu

I have a script just I want to know how to set it.

```
* 3 * * * /var/www/html/booking_cron.php
```

Comment: Check if the script is executable first. Then try to run it in Cron and if you get an error, try to google it first and ask a more specific question if your research is unsuccessful.

Comment: yes my script is ru and i m set it into windows but i dont kw how to set in ubantu - if i run 

* 3 * * * /var/www/html/booking_cron.php
this command can set it

Comment: After [your comment to the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020219/setup-a-cronjob-for-php-script-in-ubuntu-php#comment1656278_1020220) I must ask: Have you installed PHP on your Ubuntu yet?

Comment: @Melebius  yes i have php and mysql in my ubantu machine

Comment: What's your question? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Can you run the command `/var/www/html/booking_cron.php` as it is (i. e. without specifying the PHP interpreter explicitly) from a terminal? (see also [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)) Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call php binary with argument of the php script:

```
* 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/booking_cron.php
```

Be sure your path to php binary is correct.

To find the path to php: `which php` or `find / -name php`

Comment: yes path is correct but it can run properly.

Comment: you need to add php binary first, otherwise the script will not run.

Comment: what is php binary

Comment: @DEEPAKBHOSALE The php binary is `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: Could you accept the answer?

Comment: no i am not accepting your answer..